# What is a good bulk find / replace tool for windows?

Tags: search, regex, replace, bulk-action

I'm looking to find / replace in alot of files and was wondering if anybody could recommend some good tools for Windows.  I'd prefer them to be free.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I use:

for GUI
grepWin: [link text](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/grepWin)

for superfast commandline:
gsar.exe from [link text](http://home.online.no/~tjaberg/)

Answer (score 2):

Install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com), its free and gives a linux-like scriptable environment in Windows.
Do lookup the manual pages for commands I describe here (man find for example).

List files in a directory (folder) with,

```
find . -type f  
## Note: you can also select files here (see the man page)
```

Use that to search in multiple files like this,

```
grep -Hn pattern $(find . -type f)
```

Use it to replace across files like this.
Create a script file (say) `replace-in-files.sh`.
Write the following in the file,

```
#!/bin/sh
# Sample script: replace-in-files.sh
for f in $(<find . -type f);
do
    sed 's/pattern/replacement/g' $f > tmpFile.txt
    mv tmpFile.txt $f;
done;
rm -f tmpFile.txt
```

Here,
`tmpFile.txt` should be some temporary name (not already existing in the directory).
And, `pattern` is the regex you want to change with `replacement`.
Execute `chmod a+x replace-in-files.sh` and the file becomes an executable that you can fire from a Cygwin terminal with `./replace-in-files.sh`

You can build up for there for many other requirements.
To lookup manual pages for commands like `sed`, `find`, `grep` you can also `google` "manual sed" etc.

The [Advanced Bash Scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) at the Linux Documentation Project site is a good reference and most of the concepts work under Cygwin. Also has Awk, sed, briefs at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst probably not as fast as the above options - Notepad++ has a good find/replace with RegEx support.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Cygwin. If this is not desirable, on http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ you can find a bunch of standalone GNU utilities like sed, grep and find ported to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [Text WorkBench](http://www.silveragesoftware.com/hffr.html) for a while now and think it's fantastic.  It's got lots of useful features including batch replace plans, regular expressions, include/exclude file extensions, editing files inside the application, etc.

Not free though... Think it costs about $40, but is easily worth it given the amount of time it saves.  I'm not affiliated with the company in anyway, just a happy customer.

Comment: -1 Shareware, Richard asked for **freeware**

Comment: @cept0 Not quite. The exact words in the question are "I'd **prefer** them to be free" (emphasis mine).